# Network System - Cisco Packet Tracer

Tags: networking, system, packet, cisco

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfjQH.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz5eC.png)According to the network diagram above, the connection from company A's pc0 to the server system including gmail and facebook is successful, but company B's pc6 and pc7 cannot ping the server system. I tried to give ip from dns but it didn't work.

The system works normally, all devices are connected successfully, can send emails from the pc to the server